# Android L keeps killing my app in the middle of debugging...why?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an Android Lollipop device that insists on killing my app while I am connected to my app over USB using Eclipse to debug and I hit a breakpoint longer than 5 seconds. Older versions of android would give me a dialog, "Application is not responding ". Android L just kills, and it's affecting my ability to debug. I have checked the Developer options settings repeatedly for anything that might control this, to no avail.

Can anyone tell me how to enable debugging on Android L such that breakpoints don't trigger the OS to terminate my app?

Here are my debug options in Android L - nothing suggests that it will control any kind of "kill after X seconds" setting:

[image]
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Check if this solution works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39257965/4624524